# C++11 quicksort terminate called without an active exception

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency

I typed in the example below from the book on "C++ concurrency in action", but it reports:

```
"terminate called without an active exception".
```

It seems the issue is with the function of spawn_task, but I have no idea what could be wrong.

```
template<typename F, typename A>
static std::future<typename std::result_of<F(A&&)>::type> spawn_task(F&& f, A&& a)
{
    typedef typename std::result_of<F(A&&)>::type result_type;
    std::packaged_task<result_type(A&&)> task(std::move(f));
    std::future<result_type> res(task.get_future());
    std::thread(std::move(task), std::move(a));
    return res;
}
template<typename T>
static std::list<T> parallel_quick_sort(std::list<T> input)
{
    if (input.empty())
    {
        return input;
    }

    std::list<T> result;
    result.splice(result.begin(), input, input.begin());
    T const& partition_val = *result.begin();
    typename std::list<T>::iterator divide_point = std::partition(
            input.begin(), input.end(), [&](T const& t)
            {   return t<partition_val;});
    std::list<T> lower_part;
    lower_part.splice(lower_part.end(), input, input.begin(), divide_point);


    std::future<std::list<T> > new_lower(
            spawn_task(&parallel_quick_sort<T>, std::move(lower_part)));

    std::list<T> new_higher(parallel_quick_sort(std::move(input)));
    result.splice(result.end(), new_higher);
    result.splice(result.begin(), new_lower.get());
    return result;

}



static void test()
{
    std::list<int> toSort={1,4,3,6,4,89,3};
    std::for_each(std::begin(toSort), std::end(toSort), [](int n){ std::cout << n << std::endl;});
    std::list<int> sorted;
    sorted=parallel_quick_sort(toSort);
    std::for_each(std::begin(sorted), std::end(sorted), [](int n){ std::cout << n << std::endl;});
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

Err.. I figured it out after some research on google.

I fixed the code as below:

```
template<typename F, typename A>
static std::future<typename std::result_of<F(A&&)>::type> spawn_task(F&& f, A&& a)
{
    typedef typename std::result_of<F(A&&)>::type result_type;
    std::packaged_task<result_type(A&&)> task(std::move(f));
    std::future<result_type> res(task.get_future());
    std::thread myThread(std::move(task), std::move(a));
    myThread.detach();
    return res;
}
```

The error message was pointing out that I have threads that didn't join. So I should either join or detach. So I did as above.